# NULL password getted from request

Tags: php, symfony, post, request

I'm trying to get posted `username` and `password` in this way:

*[...]\src\Comflex\W2Bundle\Controller\UserController.php*

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

 public function authorizationAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new Models\User();
        $session = $request->getSession();
        
        $username = $this->get('request')->request->get('username');
        $passwd = $this->get('request')->request->get('password');
        
        var_dump($username);
        var_dump($passwd);
        die();
        
        return $this->redirectToRoute('_index');
    }
```

*[...]\src\Comflex\W2Bundle\Resources\views\Home\index.html.twig*

```
<form action="{{ path('comflex_w2_login_check') }}" method="post">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />

        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />

        <input type="submit" name="login" />
    </form>
```

But I get only `username` variable. Password (`$passwd`) is always `NULL`. Why?

> OUTPUT:
>
> string(16) "user@example.com" NULL

Comment: My bad (with "), but still not working

Comment: did you checked by using $_POST??

Comment: can you try: `$username = $request->request->get('username');` ?

Comment: Try dumping $this->get('request')->request->all(); does it give you password?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everybody! I dumped post and there was key named 'passwd'. Just need to clear cache and works again.